# xcode constrain view to size of superview

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

Call it a fetish, but I'd like to do this in Interface Builder (aka part of Xcode now) instead of programmatically. I know that I can do this (inside a ViewController):

```
NSDictionary* dict = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subview);
NSArray* constraints = 
    [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[subview]|" // Hack or cool idea??
                                            options:0
                                            metrics:nil
                                              views:dict];
// And similar for V direction.
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

But when I tell myself "this is just what IB could do for me" I am stymied. I get the "Align" and "Pin" popovers at lower-right, but most options are grey/inactive, and none seem to involve aligning or pinning to superview. Is there something wrong with my world-view of constraints, or am I just missing something?

Comment: The Pin options should not be grayed out if you've selected a view first. That's the one you want to use.

Comment: Got it. Select *both* view and superview, then in the popover, check "Equal Widths" and "Equal Heights". Too obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Once selecting a view, if you use the PIN option at the bottom right of the storyboard, the options should not be grayed out. If you notice they are still grayed out, deselect the view and select it once more. Occasionally I've selected a view and then clicked away from the screen and come back... the view still looked selected but I couldn't choose any options.

Keep in mind though that the PIN option at the bottom right is for the "spacing to closest neighbor". If you want to pin to the superview, you should select **Editor->Pin->__ to Superview**.

Comment: I am using Xcode beta so I do see a few bugs. Re the design, I wonder if there is some rationale for which options are in the popover and which in the menu... The menu item did work as you said. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem! It took me forever to realize that small detail - although it states it on the popover, it's really easy to overlook. =/ I haven't found a way yet to customize the options, but maybe they have one or will add it with the new version once it's out of beta.

Answer (score 1):

As per comment above, select *both* views, then in Pin popover, checkmark "Equal Heights" and "Equal Widths".